# Which is better? Nested `if`s or early returns?

Tags: c#, comparative-review, mvc, asp.net-core

I'm having trouble in my controller code because it looks ugly and the more i add stuffs to my controller, the more it become ugly and unreadable. Here is my codes

This is just a simply version of my first attempt

```
public IActionResult VersionOne(TestModel model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.SelectList1 = GetSelectList1();
        model.SelectList2 = GetSelectList2();
        model.SelectList3 = GetSelectList3();
        return View(model);
    }

    if(!CheckForDuplicate(model.Title))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Name already exist");
        model.SelectList1 = GetSelectList1();
        model.SelectList2 = GetSelectList2();
        model.SelectList3 = GetSelectList3();
        return View(model);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UrlFriendlyTitle))
        model.UrlFriendlyTitle = GenerateUrlFriendlyTitle(model.Title);
    else
    {
        if (CheckForDuplicate(model.UrlFriendlyTitle))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Url already exist");
            model.SelectList1 = GetSelectList1();
            model.SelectList2 = GetSelectList2();
            model.SelectList3 = GetSelectList3();
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    // do something else
    // mapping and saving to database

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

is this code, there are redundant of model assigning to send back to view

and here is my current solution to avoid the redundancy, but i will have lots of nested if statement if i add more stuff and checkings.

```
public IActionResult VersionTwo(TestModel model)
{
    bool error = false;

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(CheckForDuplicate(model.Title))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Name already exist");
            error = true;
        }

        if(!error)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UrlFriendlyTitle))
                model.UrlFriendlyTitle = GenerateUrlFriendlyTitle(model.Title);
            else
            {
                if(CheckForDuplicate(model.UrlFriendlyTitle))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Url already exist");
                    error = true;
                }
            }

            if (!error)
            {
                // do something else
                // mapping and saving to database

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
    }

    // something went wrong, re display form
    model.SelectList1 = GetSelectList1();
    model.SelectList2 = GetSelectList2();
    model.SelectList3 = GetSelectList3();
    return View(model);
}
```

so, what would be a better design for this problem? and what should i avoid in future?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: @Jamal i dont really know what title to use and i just need advice my code design

Comment: What does this code do? Surely the methods are not called `VersionOne` and `VersionTwo` in your code — what are they, really?

Comment: @200_success - I think the `VersionOne` & `VersionTwo` thing are named like that to illustrate the different options he's considering.  I suspect this is not the actual method names of his real world code.

Comment: Looks like you have a transcription error. VersionOne's second condition is !CheckForDuplicate which should be inverted.

Comment: @JohnMacIntyre I know that. On Code Review, we don't like to review code with such fabrications. Not only does it make it obscure what these functions accomplish, it makes it hard to discern which parts of the code are real and which parts are hypothetical.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'll take early exits over nested 'if's any day of the week.

However, your question is a false dichotomy and you're missing something that will allow everything else to fall into place.  Basically, the problem with your controller action is the validation.  If you extract this validation into a [custom validator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#custom-validation), your method will clean up nicely and it will become a lot simpler.  Your custom validator will be simple as well.

Comment: This is definitelly how it should be done and what validation-attributes are for.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is: "never repeat yourself":

```
    model.SelectList1 = GetSelectList1();
    model.SelectList2 = GetSelectList2();
    model.SelectList3 = GetSelectList3();
```

this is done in three places in `VersionOne()` so make a function to handle that:

```
private void HandleLists(TestModel model)
{
  model.SelectList1 = GetSelectList1();
  model.SelectList2 = GetSelectList2();
  model.SelectList3 = GetSelectList3();
}
```

---

```
        else
        {
            if(CheckForDuplicate(model.UrlFriendlyTitle))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Url already exist");
                error = true;
            }
        }
```

this is has an unnecessary nesting. Instead just do:

```
        else if(CheckForDuplicate(model.UrlFriendlyTitle))
        {
          ModelState.AddModelError("", "Url already exist");
          error = true;
        }
```

---

```
    if(CheckForDuplicate(model.Title))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Name already exist");
        error = true;
    }

    if(!error)
    { 
     .....
```

this seems odd: why not just:

```
    if(CheckForDuplicate(model.Title))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Name already exist");
        error = true;
    }
    else
    {
```

---

The calls to CheckForDuplicate(...) seems to be on the same level of concern so maybe make a combined handler for that:

```
private bool HandleDuplicates(TestModel model)
{
  if (CheckForDuplicate(model.Title))
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Name already exist");
    return false;
  }
  if (CheckForDuplicate(model.UrlFriendlyTitle))
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Url already exist");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

---

I assume that `GenerateUrlFriendlyTitle()` does not return a possible duplicate url-friendly title or else you maybe are positively redirecting to "Index" having a duplicate url-friendly title set on the model because `model.UrlFriendlyTitle = GenerateUrlFriendlyTitle(model.Title);` is not checked for duplication before returning.

---

I think it's best not to do too much nesting as it makes a flow hard to follow. Further keep it simple and do not do everything in one function. IMO it's OK to make multiple return statements in a function if it's clear why, but others may disagree.
I would do something like below:

```
public IActionResult VersionTwo(TestModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid && HandleDuplicates(model))
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UrlFriendlyTitle))
    {
      model.UrlFriendlyTitle = GenerateUrlFriendlyTitle(model.Title);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  else
  {
    // something went wrong, re display form
    HandleLists(model);
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

or if GenerateUrlFriendlyTitle may return a duplicate title:

```
public IActionResult VersionTwo(TestModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UrlFriendlyTitle))
    {
      model.UrlFriendlyTitle = GenerateUrlFriendlyTitle(model.Title);
    }

    if (HandleDuplicates(model))
    {
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
  }

  // something went wrong, re display form
  HandleLists(model);
  return View(model);
}
```